# Fill non-convex SVG path

Tags: svg, plot, polygon, fill, vector-graphics

I have a non-convex region (made from several circle arcs) and want to fill the interior region with a color. However, the fill-property will instead fill the outside, as shown in the picture. How can I achieve the interiour being filled? This is an example code:

```
<path
   id="curved_path"
   style="stroke:#000000; stroke-width:0.2px; fill:none"
   d="M 79, 66 c 0,0 -17,0 -17, 15 
      M 45, 66 c 0,0  17,0  17, 15 
      M 79, 66 c 0,0 -17,0 -17,-15 
      M 45, 66 c 0,0  17,0  17,-15" 
/>
```

Eventually, I want to write a script which draws a large number (possibly millions) of these curved polygons. If this turns out complicated in SVG, are there other languages or scriptable tools that can handle these problems better?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All those `M` commands create separate [subpaths](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataMovetoCommands) which are filled independently. You need to draw the star as one continuous path:

```html
<svg width="350" height="300" viewBox="45,51 35,30">
  <path id="curved_path"
        style="stroke:#000000; stroke-width:0.2px; fill:dodgerblue"
        d="M 79,66  c 0, 0   -17, 0   -17, 15
                    c 0,-15  -17,-15  -17,-15
                    c 0, 0    17, 0    17,-15
                    c 0, 15   17, 15   17, 15"
  />
</svg>
```